# Password Generator Program

Tags: size

```
import string
import random

def spw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
def mpw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
def wpw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

strength = str(input("How strong do you want your password to be(s/m/w): "))
if strength == 's':
    print(spw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
elif strength == 'm':
    print(mpw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
elif strength == 'w':
    print(wpw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
else:
    print("Correct command not entered")
```

/// Here my question is that even after we are defining size=8, how are we getting password with more than 8 characters///

Answer (score 0):

I dont know python, but is it possible that the parameters u give are standard parameters? In other lanuguages they will only work if nothing is entered as a parameter. If you give the function no size it will give u 8 characters

```py
import string
import random

def spw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
    if size > 8:
        size = 8
        
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
        
def mpw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
        if size > 8:
            size = 8
        
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def wpw_gen(size = 8, chars = string.ascii_letters):
        if size > 8:
            size = 8
        
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

strength = str(input("How strong do you want your password to be(s/m/w): "))
if strength == 's':
    print(spw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
elif strength == 'm':
    print(mpw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
elif strength == 'w':
    print(wpw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password: '))))
else:
    print("Correct command not entered")
```

this should work
Before u generate the password you should check if the size the user put in is larger than 8 and if so just set the size to 8

Comment: try a if statement in the funtion with something like if size > 8: size = 8

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the thing that happens here is that once the input is given by the user, the input integer value goes directly to the size value and it works as the function is defined! As for example by default

```
size = 8;
How many characters in your password: 10;
size = 10; (turns to 10)
```